# Getting the last entered word from a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, range, contenteditable

I have a div tag with contenteditable set to true.
I am trying to find out the last entered word in the div.

For example, if I type in `This is a test` and I hit a space, I want to be able to get the word `test`

I want to be able to use this logic so that I can test each word being typed (after the space is pressed).

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: There are several parts to this - extracting the contents of a `div`, reacting to changes to a `div`, splitting a string into words, deciding which word is the last one entered.  Have you made any attempt at any of these?

Comment: I have already done the first 2 parts you mentioned.. it was after that, I was stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be the following

```
var str = "This is a test "; // Content of the div
var lastWord = str.substr(str.trim().lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```

trim might need a shim for older browsers. (`.replace(/\s$/,"")`)

To strip punctuation like `" Test!!! "` you could additionally do a replace like following:

```
lastWord.replace(/[\W]/g,"");
```

You might want to do a more specific definition of the characters to omit than `\W`, depending on your needs.

If you want to trigger your eventhandler also on punctuation characters and not only on space, the last replace is not needed.

Comment: this will fail if there is punctuation before of after the word, without any space.

Comment: @Christoph - It fails again for this string: `this is,not`

Answer (score 1):

You first have to know when the content is edited. Using jQuery, that can be done with

```
​$("div").on("keyup", function(){ /* code */ });
```

Then, you'll have to get the whole text and split it into words

```
var words = $(this).text().trim().split(' ');
```

And getting the last word is as complicated as getting the last element of the `words` array.

### Here's the whole code

**HTML**

```
​<div contenteditable="true">Add text here</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JavaScript (using jQuery)**
​

```
$("div").on("keyup", function(){
    var words = $(this).text().trim().split(' '),
        lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
    console.log(lastWord);
});​​​​​​​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/L8VMd/)**

Comment: That's not a problem, at least you get the logic behind it. I'll let that here for people having the same problem but who are able to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

### This is the ultimate way:

```
// listen to changes (do it any way you want...)
document.querySelectorAll('div')[0].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    console.log( getLastWord(this.textContent) );
}, false);


function getLastWord(str){
   // strip punctuations
   str = str.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\_`~()]/g,' ');
   // get the last word
   return str.trim().split(' ').reverse()[0];
}
```

### [DEMO PAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/SH8xZ/)

Comment: Your escaping is messed up. You don't need to escape any character except `/` and `\ `. If you *do* escape them, you also have to escape characters like `{}()` for consistency too ;)

Comment: Also, headlines like "this is the ultimate way" should be used cautiously since it's most likely causing embarrassment for the writer ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel that you are angry for some reason. I don't know regex, nor care about knowing. I know only javascript for 9 years. If I did any regex mistake, so be it, I'm sorry it offended you.

Comment: @Christoph - I saw you edited your code. again, it fails.. so please don't say I'm an embarrassment, because my code works like a charm.

Comment: I'm in no way offended or angry, but rather amused. For knowing javascript so well for 9 years now, you should know, that instead of `querySelectorAll()[0]` you'd better write `querySelector()`. I just wanted to note that "ultimate way" is a very strong word quite seldom used by experienced programmers. The accepted answer served it's purpose one and a half year ago but sure feel free to get fancy on that topic.

Comment: this `querySelector` thing i wrote in 2 seconds cause it works and i had it in my clipboard, I don't care how the OP does it, jquery, vanilla or whatever, the point is to trigger the event itself, and to write the function which handles that. and `querySelector` is a relatively new thing. Anyway, your code, as I wrote, is buggy and doesn't gives the correct output, and mine is. so mine is the correct answer.

Comment: Your code is buggy too, it won't work in IE8 and also might behave wrong in IE9 since the Eventsupport for `input` is know to be buggy there. But hey, I give you an upvote for your effort :-D

Comment: my code isn't about a specific browser, it's pseudo code, my answer is ONLY the `getLastWord` function, not the lines above which are just for a person whose coming here to quickly copy-paste to his console. there are no IE users coming to Stackoverflow, so I don't bother writing cross-browser code for just a demo.

Comment: I really would like to see a proof about no IE Users coming to SO ... I know quite a handful very good developers using IE as their primary browser for several reasons... but well. Anyway, It's interesting, how fast the argument goes from the "ultimate way" to a pseudo-code solution proposal ... funny :-D

Comment: it is the ultimate way in this discussion no doubt. my `getLastWord` method works, while the other answers don't. (you can see I wrote a comment when I publish it, that the top part isn't important whatsoever)

Comment: What about punctuation from other languages like `¿¡«»`? They will make your code fail along with other simple characters like `@<>°·`. IMO an ultimate solution should account these too... ;)

Comment: This is currently the ultimate solution for this thread, not the whole universe nor any parallel universes. If you have a better one, then you can write.

Comment: Well, you are pretty inconsistent in your statements. Either you claim your answer is ultimate - in that case you have to offer a complete solution (which invalidates your last statement) - or your claim is incorrect. After all, OP asked for whitespace only, which I offered a solution for. I never claimed to offer an ultimate solution, but for the OP it worked perfectly  which is the case it was accepted. However, you claimed to offer a perfect solution which you obviously didn't. Excuses won't change that. Result: Verbal FAIL. Case closed. Have a nice day :-D

Comment: you solution cannot work perfectly for anybody, since it does not give the true last word for a simple case such as I described in your solution. my solution is the ultimate, I do not contradict myself, I don't see why you would say that. The OP gave an example of a line to get the last word from, it could be any line obviously. I chose to write here so people could have a true answer.

Comment: This returns last word from element not last entered word.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get last word from a editable div.

**HTML**

```
<div id='edit' contenteditable='true' onkeypress="getLastWord(event,this)">
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
 function getLastWord(event,element){
             var keyPressed = event.which;
             if(keyPressed == 32){ //Hits Space
                 var val = element.innerText.trim();
                 val = val.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
                 var idx = val.lastIndexOf(' ');
                 var lastWord = val.substring(idx+1);
                 console.log("Last Word " + lastWord);
             }
        }
```

Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/vV2mN/18/

Comment: thank you for the code.. but I am unable to edit anything in the div tag in the fiddle link you provided

Comment: @learner2010 Firefox restricted to edit a element without giving height . I updated my link please try now.

Comment: thank you for the updated link.. new to jsfiddle.. where would I see the console output?