# Detect Word Entered in ContentEditable div

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, contenteditable, jsni

I have a requirement where I need to get the word that was typed in a `contenteditable` div.

Whenever I type a word and hit space I want to know what word was typed. The word can be typed towards the end or anywhere on between.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript then this stack overflow link is useful :

[get the text content from a contenteditable div through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593626/get-the-text-content-from-a-contenteditable-div-through-javascript)

Comment: For my usecase i have an event 'wordentered'. This event gets fired when user hits space or enter. This event expects the word that was typed.
So how do I get what word was typed when the user hit space or enter?

Comment: I have 2 doubts                                                      1.Do you mean to say when you hit enter/space in the contenteditable div,they are considered part of the input and hence the event is not getting fired?                                                                         2.Is this issue any browser specific?

Comment: 1. No there is no issue firing the event. The event gets fired when spaces/enter is hit. My requirement is that when user hits space/enter, i want the word he has typed before hitting space/enter. How do I get the word that the user has typed. I don't want the complete textvalue of the contenteditable div, but as and when the user goes tying & hitting space/enter, i want to detect the word he has typed on every space/enter encountered. This word will be passed to the event eventually, but before this i want the word the user has typed when he hits space/enter.
2. No it is not browser specific.

Comment: So you mean to say you want to retrieve the immediately last word before hitting enter? try the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917750/getting-the-last-entered-word-from-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: Yes, but this works if it is the last word is at the end. What about words that have been entered that aren't at the end? Say you're inputting in the middle of the text.

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil : What you are telling will not work for the askers requirement. Look at my answer for a change :), I hope it solves the askers problem

Answer (score 0):

In GWT I believe `contentEditable` div refers to `Textbox`, `Numberbox` or `RichTextArea`. (If any others are there, let me know).

The solution looks fairly simple.

You can easily override the `onBrowseEvent()` for each of the above said widgets. Once the keystrokes matches either `space or Enter` get the value from the div and store it in `current value or any other string`. Maintain a `previous value` String and compare with it. Once you encounter the first change in the String, you got word which you were looking for.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use on keyUp event to check for space and than use a diff algorithm to check for changes made.
see google for "javascript diff" algos - you will masses ....